# How to iterate through a vector of class pointer

Tags: c++, debugging, pointers, vector, stl

I have a class `User`

```
class User
{
        public:
            User();
            User(string, string);
            virtual string getRole();

            void setPW(string);
            void setID(string);
            string getPW();
            string getID();

        protected:
            string id;
            string pw;
};
```

And several subclasses which inherit from `User`

```
class Customer : public User
{
        public:
            Customer();
            Customer(string, string,string,string, string, string, string, string, string);

                        virtual string getRole();
                        string getSname();
                        string getFname();
                        string getTitle();
                        string getAddress();
                        string getTown();
                        string getCity();
                        string getPostalCode();

                        void setSname(string);
                        void setFname(string);
                        void setTitle(string);
                        void setAddress(string);
                        void setTown(string);
                        void setCity(string);
                        void setPostalCode(string);




        private:
            string sname;
            string fname;
            string title;
            string address;
            string town;
            string city;
            string postalcode;
};
```

All the information is stored inside a vector which contains pointers to the class `User`

```
 vector<User*> userVector
```

**How do i iterate through the vector of pointers to a class and call the respective methods of the class ??**

**If its a vector of User object , i can declare an iterator `vector<User>::iterator p` , is there something equivalent for pointers to a object and how do i call the respective method of the class depending on the object**

**EDIT , this is what i have tried**

```
vector<User*>::iterator p;

    p=userVector.begin();

    while ( p != userVector.end() )
    {

        //how to dereference
        p++;
    }
```

Comment: one thing at a time. as always, show us what you have tried

Comment: Do you know how to use pointers *outside* vectors? If so, add that knowledge to the knowledge you're displaying here. If not, go back a step and learn that first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterators behave like pointers in the way that they can be dereferenced and incremented (other operations depend on iterator category).

If you have a vector of pointers, then dereferencing its iterator gives you a pointer. That means you need to dereference once more to get to members. Assuming `it` is the iterator:

```
    (*it) -> getID()
//  ^     ^^
//  |     second dereferencing
//  first dereferencing
```

Answer (score 3):

I recommend following 3 solutions in its priority order. You can select whatever you are comfortable with.

1. If you are using C++11 features, you can use range based loops for easy syntax. That's always advisable too.
2. Use for_each loop.
3. Otherwise, use like this which would be more optimal.

   ```
   for( vector<User*>::iterator itr = userVector.begin(), itr_end = userVector.end(); itr != itr_end; ++itr )
   {
       std::cout << (*itr)->getRole() << std::endl;
   }
   ```

Here you are not going to receive the end iterator each iteration of loop traversal.

Answer (score 1):

An iterator basically functions like a pointer, so you can consider `vector<TYPE>::iterator` to be the equivalent of `TYPE*`

This means `vector<TYPE*>::iterator` equates to `TYPE**`

So to get at your functions, you just need to dereference the iterator:

```
for( vector<User*>::iterator iter = userVector.begin(); iter != userVector.end(); ++iter )
{
    std::cout << (*iter)->getRole() << std::endl;
}
```